# JS helper submit works but link wouldn't

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I have a need to use a link and not submit in JS helper. Unfortunately my submit code works fine but when I try to switch the same code from submit to link by changing $this->Js->submit to $this->Js->link it doesn't work

**This works**

```
echo $this->Js->submit("Delete", array(
    'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
    'success'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
    'update'=>'#success',
    'url' => array(
    'action' => 'delete',$team['Team']['id']
    ),                      
));
```

**This doesn't work**

```
 echo $this->Js->link("Delete", array(
        'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
        'success'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
        'update'=>'#success',
        'url' => array(
        'action' => 'delete',$team['Team']['id']
        ),                      
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok found the solution

this works

```
<?php  
      echo $this->Js->link('Delete', 
                                array(
                                   'action' => 'edit_reload',
                                   'team_id'=>$team['Team']['id']
                                 ), 
                                 array(
                                   'update' => '#success'
                                 )
                          ); 
?>
```